# use Partial in nested property with typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type like this;

```
interface State {
  one: string,
  two: {
    three: {
      four: string
    },
    five: string
  }
}
```

I make state Partial like this `Partial<State>`

But how can I make on of the nested properties partial, for example if I wanted to make `two` also partial.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You can pretty easily define your own `RecursivePartial` type, which will make all properties, included nested ones, optional:

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]>;
};
```

If you only want some of your properties to be partial, then you can use this with an intersection and `Pick`:

```
type PartialExcept<T, K extends keyof T> = RecursivePartial<T> & Pick<T, K>;
```

That would make everything optional *except* for the keys specified in the `K` parameter.

Comment: `Partial` + `Pick` is a great combination. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: And the reverse for Required instead of Partial:

`export type RecursiveRequired<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: RecursiveRequired<T[P]>;
};
`

Comment: @CRice running into some compilation errors when one or the properties is an array of type any. Any reason you can think of for this, or advice? Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zscugv

Comment: Using `any[]` in the type won't work:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0CM5WQbwChlkZMAuZEAVwFstoBuY5HKSokks9AJkrggAngG0AusxIBfZlMKEwQgA4oAIhAhKACrjDA4AGwA8AFQB8yALwEWJEVuShkAawhD0MZCbEB+Sus0dKD1DU3sxM1lmQgR0EABnMFJMNn8NbV19YwxsXAtrTmT0SgBGABoWVIJkWyL+EVqSQq4uVyES8gByADdDaghOipaWtv4AZkbkOWGxFjkZIA

Comment: @MCFreddie777 There's always a way, you just need to capture that case somehow. For example, using `type DeepPartial<T> = T extends never[] ? T : {[P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>}` will properly capture items of type `any[]` and you can continue to adjust it if needed for additional types.

Comment: I needed a `PartialExcept` that would pass the "except" part down to the nested children (in my case all `id` props should be nonNullable) so I ended up with the following (also fixing arrays)
`type DeepPartialExcept<T, E extends keyof T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Array<infer R>
    ? Array<DeepPartialExcept<R, E extends keyof R ? E : never>>
    : DeepPartialExcept<T[K], E extends keyof T[K] ? E : never>
} & Pick<T, E>
`

Comment: Thanks @CRice . The one that you provided in comments will fix issue with this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIAUCGyw6eANgDwAqAfFALxQDeAUFK1ANo5ToB2UA1hBAB7AGZQKAXQD8ALlgIUGbPkLFyFTpKoBuJgF89TUJAngIARjqMWbCuYsB9ANJCLcm2y8dBIeamBkXgBzSXk8HhA9L0MDJmNzKABlYQBbCHtTemYvXwt-QJDotl8AJgKgnmDi1l8AZg9MyziE0xT0poB5MCJhHlJrOCQ0LFwCIlIydozzXXj4PoCoVDSIADVSREt5aa6e9D6B7Ntat3kAcnOAGhOBITr5HO9WJqdXEHzPZ+9RYWRUgByeHSF3Otxit30LQWPCWK3SGxIW3KyVWTWsT1OH1BN1yQhRl1xJXuj3BdgcLjOX2+bF+-yBIKglzJrChEP0QA

Comment: I need the opposite. Only some nested key required, does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 33):

This is possible, you can create a 'deep' partial type as followed:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
};
```

Which can be used as followed

```
const state: DeepPartial<State> = {
    two: {
        three: {
            four: '4'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

#### Array properties on Objects

For TypeScript 2.8 or later, the following type should fix problem about Array property:

```
type NestedPartial<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Array<infer R> ? Array<NestedPartial<R>> : NestedPartial<T[K]>
};
```

Please see the example below.

```
interface Foo {
    NumProp: number;
    SubItem: Foo;
    SubItemArray: Foo[];
}
```

**Valid Result with conditional type**

[image: Valid Result]

**Invalid Result**

[image: Invalid Result]

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

Answer (score 4):

Try to exclude the nested Property, and add it again as Partial:

```
interface Foo {
    someName: Partial<Omit<MainType, 'lvl2Partial'> & { lvl2Partial: Partial<SubType> }>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's useful when you don't want recursive in basic type.

```js
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: typeof T[P] extends Record<string, unknown> ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> : T[P];
};
```

Comment: This one works with an custom object type that has entries with other custom object types. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

### TypeScript: Convert All Properties and Nested Properties of an Object to Optional

This TypeScript snippet defines a `PartialNested<T>` type, which converts all properties and nested properties of an object to optional. This is useful when working with data structures where you need flexibility in specifying which properties are required or optional.

```js
    type PartialNested<T> = {
      [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? PartialNested<T[K]> : T[K];
    };

    type Client = {
      id: number;
      fullName: string | null;
      user: {
        id: number;
        email: string;
      };
    }
    
    // Example original object
    const originalObject: Client = {
      id: 1,
      fullName: 'John Doe',
      user: {
        id: 1,
        email: 'john@example.com',
      },
    };
    
    // Example using PartialNested
    const updatedObject: PartialNested<Client> = {
      id: 10,
      user: {
        id: 1,
      },
    };
```