# How to gracefully override an object while strictly checking it's nested properties

Tags: typescript

If we have

```
interface Human{
  name:string
  age:number
  dimensions : {
    height:number
    width:number
  }
}

const base : Human ={
  name:"Base",
  age:12,
  dimensions : {
    height:190,
    width:99
  }
};


const child : Human = lodashMerge(base,{
  age:22,
  dimentions:{
     height:99
  }
}) // this should work , shouldn't throw 


const child2 : Human = lodashMerge(base,{
  hairColor:'red'
}) // should throw because hairColor does not exist in base
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `lodashMerge` is lodash's `_.merge` method, you won't be able to do this and keep using that method alone. You'll have to wrap it into your own function to which you can add a stricter type definition, since the definition given by lodash itself is too permissive.

[The type definition for that method can be found here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/object.d.ts#L2532), and as you can see, the return type for each overload is just the intersection type of its arguments, where it sounds like you want the return type to be just exactly the type of the first argument.

So I would recommend wrapping the method into your own function with the signature you want. Something like this maybe:

```
// Using only the final overload (the variadic one), since thats how we call it later.
declare function lodashMerge(object: any, ...otherArgs: any[]): any;

type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K]>;
}

function myMerge<T>(base: T, ...args: DeepPartial<T>[]): T {
    return lodashMerge(base, ...args);
};
```

Then, using that, you'll get an error on your second example, but not on the first. *Although actually, you get an error on both since you misspelled "dimensions"* ;)

```
// No problem, works as expected.
const child : Human = myMerge(base,{
  age:22,
  dimensions:{ // Note the change in spelling, otherwise: error.
     height:99
  }
})

// Error: See below
const child2 : Human = myMerge(base,{
  hairColor:'red' // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'hairColor' does not exist in type 'DeepPartial<Human>'.
})
```

Comment: Nice! Sharing a link that provides related info on using `Partial` for objects with nested properties - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914536/use-partial-in-nested-property-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code left out the bit that determines if an error will be detected. It depends on how `lodashMerge` was defined.

If you want to pass partial objects, consider `Partial<Human>` as the parameter type for the `lodashMerge` function. Otherwise, you can `{ age: 99 } as any` to bypass type checks.

Comment: Thanks , but don't wanna bypass the checks, that's the whole point