# Typescript interface for same type of objects but one must have all the fields while others may skip the fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

Let's say I have three objects

```js
const common = {
   app: {
     port: 8080
   }
};

const development = {
   app: {
     port: 5000
   }
};

const production = {};
```

I want to create an interface for these objects, but for the object with name `common` all fields are required, but others may skip the fields, as these will be picked from the `common` later if not present.

I have created an interface like this

```js
 export interface Settings {
    app: { port: number }
 }
```

Now, `common` will implement this interface like:

```js
import { Settings } from "./types"; 

/** common should implement all the fields defined in Settings interface */
const common: Settings = {
   app: {
     port: 8080
   }
};
```

I want `development` and `production` objects to implement `Settings` interface as well but they should be allowed to skip the fields

If I do `const production: Settings = {}`, I get an error as expected as I have not defined all the required properties of `Settings` interface. To work around this, I am doing this:

```js
export interface OptionalSettings {
    app?: { port?: number }
}
```

I've created a new interface `OptionalSettings`, now my `development` and `production` objects implements the `OptionalSettings` interface instead of the `Settings` interface like so

```js
const prodSettings: OptionalSettings = {}
```

Now, my code is working as expected, I am not allowed to use any other property except those defined in `Settings` interface and can skip them as well. Since this is not an ideal solution, I am forced to keep two interfaces in sync. The one with values, and others with optional values. Is there a more straightforward way of doing this?

Below is my interface file

```js
export interface Settings {
    app: { port: number }
}

export interface OptionalSettings {
    app?: { port?: number }
}
```

Comment: You can use the built in `Partial` type helper. EG: `type OptionalSettings = Partial<Settings>`. If you need nested properties to be optional, [you can define your own recursive partial type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914536/use-partial-in-nested-property-with-typescript/47914631#47914631), then use `type OptionalSettings = RecursivePartial<Settings>`.

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me to Recursive Partial as I want nested properties to be optional as well

Answer (score 1):

You can extends interface and use Partial

```js
export interface Settings {
    app: { port: number }
}

interface MyType extends Settings {}

const foo:Partial<MyType> = {}
```