# How to declare nested partial type for complex types?

Tags: typescript

I trying to do all [JSONSchemaType](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/blob/cde708d1522fc65e8dd556c73adca8d2c17d13d9/lib/types/json-schema.ts) nested propoerty optional.
i tried (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47914643/1434301) answer):

```
import { JSONSchemaType as _JSONSchemaType } from "ajv";
type NestedPartial<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Array<infer R> ? Array<NestedPartial<R>> : NestedPartial<T[K]>
};

export declare type JSONSchemaType<T> = NestedPartial<_JSONSchemaType<T>>;
const a: JSONSchemaType<number> = { minimum:2 };
```

the error is - Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'NestedPartial<unknown>[] | NestedPartial<any> | undefined

there is no simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to fix it -

```
type NestedPartial<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Array<infer R> ? Array<NestedPartial<R>> : (T[K] extends unknown ? unknown : NestedPartial<T[K]>)
};
```