# Making properties of nested type optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types, conditional-types

I am working with auto generated types from a library. The types contain all values as required whereas I would like to mark some of them as optional. I know this is possible using generics in typescript but not sure how to do it. Here is an example what I would like to happen:

So this is an example of type with nested types:

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    hometown: string;
    nickname: string;
    data:{
        address:string,
        phone:number
    }
}
```

I am looking to invoke something like following to make the `name` property in root type and `address` property in nested type as optional:

```js
type TransformedPerson = MakeOptional<Person,{name:string, data:{address:string}}>
```

or:

```js
type TransformedPerson = MakeOptional<Person,"name"|"data.address">
```

Expecting to see the following type created:

```js
/*
type TransformedPerson = {
    name?: string;
    hometown: string;
    nickname: string;
    data:{
        address?:string,
        phone:number
    }
}
*/
```

I've seen an example to [use Partial in nested property with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914536/use-partial-in-nested-property-with-typescript) for making properties optional in the root object but it does not work for nested type:

```js
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]>;
};

type PartialExcept<T, K extends keyof T> = RecursivePartial<T> & Pick<T, K>;

type TransformedType = PartialExcept<Person, "name"> /// This works only for root type

type TransformedType = PartialExcept<Person, "name"|"data.address"> /// throws error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach based on a tuple that defines the optional keys:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    hometown: string;
    nickname: string;
    data: {
        address: string;
        phone: number;
    }
}

type NestedKeys<T extends string, U extends string[]> = {
  [K in keyof U]: U[K] extends `${T}.${infer V}` ? V : never;
}

type PartialExcept<T, U extends string[]> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends U[number] ? K : never]?: T[K]
} & {
  [K in keyof T as K extends U[number] ? never : K]: K extends string
    ? PartialExcept<T[K], NestedKeys<K, U>>
    : T[K]
}

type TransformedPerson = PartialExcept<Person, ['name', 'data.address']>

const p: TransformedPerson = {
  hometown: 'Sometown',
  nickname: 'Somename',
  data: {
    phone: 132456789
  }
};
```

The `PartialExcept` type defines a new type based on the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of two [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html): one containing the optional properties of which the keys are present in the string tuple, and one containing the remaining required properties.

The `PartialExcept` type uses itself recursively. For nested objects, the `NestedKeys` type is used to create a mapped tuple type that only contains the descendant keys of a given property.

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESQBZaVhYDuINOgxAs2xEMAQBrMpUH0mrEsgAmcMHBqFlyuCpVQIGDPOGidJAA6cQ1UgFdyAI2hKSAXwKeCYAJ6WUADkjSBUAaQhfDAAeABVkCAAPSBAVDFoFEQAaZABVBOSIVPShJgBtAF0APmQAXnw2MrDkUGQpSKwYPIqaXKaKgpS05AADABI8WPcAOgnQGGhkADV3EeQAfmXkGlsAN1cvAh9-FFQ4KDBgOAAbAFFEpEswOJz8pKGSzMZKmvrtZCaLVw7V8nWQ8Tg6Wa7yKwz6IEcLigA02zR2EH2yPWNFi-S8yAAZA1iIDWiCwRCoYNYel4YjoCjSBjFjQwj1kNDCsUMmYxBs0OdLjd7o9nri2TlgnQIOFIjEwq8qlU+Ti8d4-AFwVA4CAMDAsFBKCp0FBsLh6mcLlc7g8IE9oiazTkygByWQQF05F1qDTTPQGIwYF3VI4IHB0ZCWHHa3X6w0yx04OrE5Ccbh8ATIF0AZS4EB4-E9bAk0ndNBzefdReIPs0KeI1hwdgAjABmABMABYAKwANgA7AAOACcbE87mYQA)

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. Still failing to understand how `U[number]` works but I believe it is doing the actual magic!